# AttributeError: module 'email.encoders' has no attribute 'endcode_base64'

Tags: python

New to python. Trying to send an email with attachment but keep receiving the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'email.encoders' has no attribute
>   'endcode_base64'

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

print("Enter recipients addrss")
toaddr = input()
print("Enter senders addrss")
fromaddr = input()
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
print("Enter subjectline")
msg['Subject'] = input()

print("Type message")
body = input()
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
```

## Attach file: convert file to Base64 to send text files, pdf, images, audio and video files.

## print("Enter name of file with its extension")

## Enter 'none' if no attachments

```
print("Enter filename, No attachments? Enter none")
filename = input(" ")
if filename != "none":
    print("Enter path of file")
    attachment = open(input(), "rb")

part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.endcode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment;filename= %s" % 
filename)

msg.attach(part)

if toaddr.endswith(gmail):
    mail= smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    mail.starttls()

    mail.login(input(), input())
    text = msg.as_string()
    mail.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    mail.close() 
else:

    if toaddr.endswith(outlook):
        mail= smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com',587)
        mail.starttls()

        mail.login(input(), input())
        text = msg.as_string()
        mail.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
        mail.close()
```

Comment: post the complete traceback of the error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./email2.py", line 42, in <module>
    encoders.endcode_base64(part)
AttributeError: module 'email.encoders' has no attribute 'endcode_base64'

Comment: You have a typo - `endcode_base64` should be `encode_base64`